# Display D3.js label text into two lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a funnel chart using [the D3Funnel library](http://jakezatecky.github.io/d3-funnel/) . I am able to render the chart and display my data but since I am drawing it in a very small size widthwise, the text labels for the categories often overflow out of the funnel. Which doesn't look very pleasing. So now my idea is to display the labels in two lines; in the first line will be the cateogry and in the second line I want to display the amount.

To be able to do so, I tried following the various examples available here to text wrap the labels/text but I haven't been able to make any progress. So it will be great if someone can help me out here.

http://jsfiddle.net/NewMonk/s76oap3d/1/

I feel that the relevant place where I need to make the change is somewhere in the below part of the code but not able to figure out how shall I go about it:

```
{
 key: '_addBlockLabel',
 value: function _addBlockLabel(group, index) {
        var paths = this.blockPaths[index];

        var label = this._getBlockData(index)[0].formatted;
        var fill = this.data[index][3] || this.label.fill;

        var x = this.width / 2; // Center the text
        var y = this._getTextY(paths);

        group.append('text').text(label).attr({
            'x': x,
            'y': y,
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'dominant-baseline': 'middle',
            'fill': fill,
            'pointer-events': 'none'
        }).style('font-size', this.label.fontSize);
    }

    /**
   * Returns the y position of the given label's text. This is determined by
   * taking the mean of the bases.
   *
   * @param {Array} paths
   *
   * @return {Number}
   */
   }, {
  key: '_getTextY',
    value: function _getTextY(paths) {
        if (this.isCurved) {
            return (paths[2][1] + paths[3][1]) / 2 + this.curveHeight / this.data.length;
        }

        return (paths[1][1] + paths[2][1]) / 2;
    }
}]);
```

Regards

Comment: Could you maybe add a jsfiddle with your code?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append two `text` elements instead of one.

Playing with the code it seems that you have access to both the label and the value, so just need to append them separately, with a `dy` property in order to separate them vertically:

```
key: '_addBlockLabel',
value: function _addBlockLabel(group, index) {
    var paths = this.blockPaths[index];

    var text  = this.blocks[index].label.raw;
    var value = this.blocks[index].value;
    var fill  = this.blocks[index].label.color;

    var x = this.width / 2; // Center the text
    var y = this._getTextY(paths);

    group.append('text').text(text).attr({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        dy: -10,
        fill: fill,
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'dominant-baseline': 'middle',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
    }).style('font-size', this.label.fontSize);

    group.append('text').text(value).attr({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        dy: 10,
        fill: fill,
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'dominant-baseline': 'middle',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
    }).style('font-size', this.label.fontSize);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38kkctqh/